# Find sum of numbers from $1-100$ which are not divisible by $3$ and$ 7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Question explains everything but I'm stuck at a certain part. I found:

- sum of numbers from $1-100$
- sum of numbers from $1-100$ divisible by $3$
- sum of numbers from $1-100$ divisible by $7$

Then subtracted first sum by last $2$ sums as mentioned above but there are certain numbers that appear in both tables. Ex: $21$ in $3$ and $7$, next is $42$, $63$ and $84$
My question is how to find these numbers ? I can't check every number from $1-100$. Is there any formula for this ?

Comment: See [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006042703141) and do the same for $(3,7)$ instead of $(3,5)$.

Comment: Do you mean "$3$ and $7$" or "$3$ or $7$" ?

Comment: Hint: the numbers that appear in both tables are multiples of $21$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are familiar with unions and intersections of sets , then it is not a difficult problem.

**Your answer should be:**  Total sum-(sum of multiple of $3 +$ sum of multiple of $7 -$ sum of multiple of $21)$

Since $21$ is LCM of $3$ & $7$

Comment: The word you used "LCM" made my concept clear. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure whether the analogy with sets is helpful here, since sets don't have a notion of "negative membership", so the sum of the elements in $\mathbb{N}_{100} \setminus (3\,\mathbb{N}_{100} \cup 7\,\mathbb{N}_{100})$ would be exactly right, since the multiples of $21$ don't need to be "added back in".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor If you define the "summation measure" on $\mathbb{N}$ to be $\mu(\{x\}) = x$, then invoking the Inclusion-Exclusion principle shows this.

Answer (score 6):

Sum of numbers divisible by $3=1683$

Sum of numbers divisible by $7=735$

Sum of numbers divisible by $21=210$

**We need the sum of divisor of $21$ since if we subtract only by the Sum of divisor of $3$ and Sum of divisor of $7$ then the numbers those are divisible by both $3$ & $7$ means divisible by $21$ will be subtracted twice but we need to subtract it only once.**

$\therefore$
 The sum of numbers not divisible by $3$ & $7=$ Sum of first $100$ natural numbers $-$ Sum of divisor of $3-$ Sum of divisor of $7+$ Sum of divisor of $21$

$=5050-1683-735+210$

$=2842$

Comment: Shouldn't it be 5050 instead of 10100?

Comment: I beg your pardon

Answer (score 6):

Number of multiples of $3$ between $1$ & $100$ = $[\frac{100}{3}]$ = $33$,

Number of multiples of $7$ between $1$ & $100 =$ $[\frac{100}{7}]$ = $14$,

Number of multiples of $21$ between $1$ & $100$ = $[\frac{100}{21}]$ = $4$,

Where $[x]$ is the box function.

**Sum of first 100 terms excluding terms divisible by $3$ and $7$**:

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{100} i - 3\sum_{i=1}^{33} i - 7\sum_{i=1}^{14} i + 21\sum_{i=1}^4 i.
$$

Apply the formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ and take it from here.

Comment: Fair and easy. +1

Answer (score 3):

Its simple find the sum of terms divisible by 21.
And add this sum.

**Sum of first 100 terms excluding terms divisible by 3 and 7 = Sum of first 100 terms - Sum of terms divisible by 3 - Sum of terms divisible by 21 + Sum of terms divisible by 21.**

Because when you are subtracting the sum of terms divisible by 3 and sum of terms divisible by 7 few terms which are divisible by both subtracted twice. So add sum of terms divisible by 21.

> Update -  Answer with explanation.

Numbers divisible by 3 are 3, 6, 9, ...., 99.

Numbers divisible by 7 are 7, 14, 21, 28, ...., 98.

Numbers divisible by 21 are 21, 42, 63, 84.

Now we have sum of first 100 numbers not divisible by 3 and 7 is

(1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 100) - (3 + 6 + 9 + .... + 99) - (7 + 14 + 21 + .... + 98) + (21 + 42 + 63 + 84)

= (1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 100) - 3(1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 33) - 7(1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 14) + 21(1 + 2 + 3 + 4)

Using formula -

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{n} k = \tfrac{1}{2} (n)(n+1)$$

We have,

$ = \frac12 (100)(101) - 3 \cdot \frac12 (33)(34) - 7\cdot \frac12 (14)(15) + 21 \cdot \frac12 (4)(5)$

$= 5050 - 1683 - 735 + 210$

$= 2842$

Answer (score 1):

First posted as a hint, but now it is the compilation to @Atul Mishra's answer.

Let us see what is happening in diagrammatic way:

[image: Image Describing unions and intersections]

Now, look at the image carefully.The coloured regions represent following data:

*The rectangle: Sum of All the numbers from $1-100$.*

*White region: Sum of Numbers that are neither multiple of $3$ nor of $7$.*

*Green region: Sum of Numbers that are multiple of $3$ only.*

*Blue region: Sum of Numbers that are multiple of $7$ only.*

*Light blue region: Sum of Numbers that are multiple of $3$ and $7$.*

We have to find the sum of numbers which are neither divisible by $3$ nor by $7$. So, we will find the sum of numbers that are in white region.

Sum of Numbers in white region $=$ Sum of Numbers in Rectangle $-$ Sum of Numbers in (Dark blue $+$ Light Blue) $-$ Sum of Numbers in (Green + Light Blue) $+$ Sum of Numbers in light blue region.

From here we get the formula used by other answers. i.e.,

Sum of Required numbers $=$ Sum of Total Numbers $-$ Sum of Numbers divisible by $7-$ Sum of Numbers divisible by $3+$ Sum of Numbers divisible by both $3$ and $7$.

Next question you may ask is that, How to find the sum of numbers from $1-100$ or sum of multiples of $3$ etc.

There is no problem in it, you just have to identify the A.P.

Sum of numbers from $1$ to $100$ equals  $\frac{100}{2}\times {101}$.

Sum of multiples of $3$ equals $\frac{33}{2}\times 102$.
......
......
......

I think I shall let you conclude now. :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use programmatic approach to answer your questions, which I personally find way easier than hand-written-math, you can check out that simple **[JavaScript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deshu/kzx4rxa3/6/)** I wrote for you.

**In the right bottom corner you can find answers for you questions.**

You can easily change code to, for example, find all numbers in range 100-1000 if you need to.
In that case, you would have to change line:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
```

to:

```
for (var i = 100; i <= 1000; i++) {
```

Every time you want your output to update, you have to click **Run** button at the top.

I'd gladly answer to any questions about code, if you have any.

*Remember that the bottom right window won't wrap text, so the horizontal scrolling is possible.*

Comment: For text wrap, include spaces in the output. Hint:  `Array.join(", ")`

Comment: Other way to fix text wrap, is to add this line in CSS (top-right):
`div { word-wrap: break-word; }`